# How to insert data into ManyToManyField in django from views.py

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from item.models import Item
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Catalog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my views.py

```
def catalog(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    qs = Item.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = catalogForm(qs,request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            title=form.cleaned_data['title']
            item=form.cleaned_data['item']
            user= request.user
            q = Catalog(title=title, pub_date=timezone.now(),user=user)
            q.save()
            q.item = item.values()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = catalogForm(qs)

    return render(request, 'catalog/catalog.html', {'form': form})
```

Now `item = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True, null=True)` creating 2 tables `catalog_catalog` and `catalog_catalog_item` as it should be. With `q.save()` I am able to insert data in to single table `catalog_catalog` but I am not able to insert data into `catalog_catalog_item`.

What I am missing here. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I tried actually but getting error `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QuerySet'`

Comment: items = list(item)
q.item.add(*items)

Comment: Cool , it worked . Thanks a lot. Can you please explain why we need to convert it into `list` and post answer. I will accept it

Comment: `list(queryset)` actually executes the query. Before that, it's a QuerySet object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[add()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) accepts an arbitrary number of arguments, not a list of them.

```
add(obj1, obj2, obj3, ...)
```

To expand that list into arguments, use `*`

```
add(*[obj1, obj2, obj3])
```

use this as (@EchoUA Team) mentioned in comments

```
items = list(item)
q.item.add(*items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second "save()" call.

```
q = Catalog(title=title, pub_date=timezone.now(),user=user)
q.save()
q.item = item.values()
q.save()       # you need this save as well
```